# QueryDslPredicateExecutor: Predicate from two tables

Tags: spring-data, querydsl

I have this QueryDSL Predicate:

```
public class Predicates {
    public static Predicate get() {
        QUser qUser = QUser.user;
        QUserCompany qUserCompany = QUserCompany.userCompany;
        return qUser.id.eq(qUserCompany.userId);
    }
}
```

as you see, I need two tables to query users (`User` and `UserCompany`), so I get an error when I declare my repository like this:

```
public interface UserRepository QueryDslPredicateExecutor<User>
{
}
```

because internally `UserCompany` table is not included in the query (`QueryDslPredicateExecutor<User>`).

```
List<User> users = userRepository.findAll(Predicates.get());
```

How can I build a Predicate using two tables and use it with `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I have mapped the one-to-many relationship in the User entity to UserCompany and then:

```
public class Predicates {
    public static Predicate get() {
        QUser qUser = QUser.user;
        return qUser.userCompanies.any().userId.eq(qUser.id);
    }
}
```